# Unable to map owner field

Tags: contact

[image: Kindly refer the attached image]
 I have renamed Contact Owner field as "User ID" (which is editable). Now I want to create a field (Record Owner) which should have the same value/ Full Name which is in the Contact Owner field. I tired to create a formula field (Kindly refer the attached image) but its only gives me the option to select either First or last name. I also tried another formula- "Owner.Contact.OwnerId" but its remains blank when saving a Contact. Please suggest what is the workaround for this requirement. Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks you missed the image

Comment: Oops... added the image

Comment: You can have First Name + Last Name since you are using a formula field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have Formula(text) field you can concatenate strings. So here you can have a formula like below to achieve your task.

```
Owner.FirstName + " " + Owner.LastName
```